# Swift 2 colored background of UITableViewCell at certain indexPath.rows

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2, uitableview

I have an `iOS` Xcode 7.3 project written in Swift 2.  I have a `UITableView` that contains an `array` of information of type `[String]` called `details`.  When the user clicks on one of the `UITableViewCells`, it `segues` them to another `ViewController` where they can enter notes for that selected `detail`.  Afterwards they can `segue` back to the `UITableView`. My goal is if a `detail` in the `UITableView` has a note attached that was typed, that cell's `backgroundColor` would be yellow.

Below is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Transfer details of selected cell to notes view
    var selectedCell = details[indexPath.row]
    detailsTransfer = selectedCell // Transfer detail information
    detailLocation = indexPath.row // Transfer detail location in array

}
```

This transfers the `details` and `location` in the `array` for adding notes to the `detail`.  I then save the `detailLocation` to a new `array` of type `Int`. I'm thinking to get the color change in the `cell` `background`, I'd need to loop through the `[Int]` and only those `cells` in the `UITableView` would have a `backgroundColor` of `yellowColor()`?  I don't know if this is correct and/or how/where this code would go.  Maybe the loop in: `tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!` ??  Can someone please help? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let cellIdentifier = "LogTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LogTableViewCell

    cell.logLabel?.text = details[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Still trying to compare `indexPath.row` for color change.

Comment: Are you trying to highlight a cell when it is selected, or make certain cells yellow depending on state?

Comment: Please post your cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main table view, `tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!` method, you can do something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell! {

    // Transfer details of selected cell to notes view
    var selectedCell = details[indexPath.row]
    detailsTransfer = selectedCell // Transfer detail information
    detailLocation = indexPath.row // Transfer detail location in array

    if selectedCell.hasNote {

      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
   } 
}
```

You don't need to loop because the table view data source already checks each row for you.

Comment: This will set the background if the cell is selected.

Comment: Whoops! Meant `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Thank you. (Fixed.)

Comment: I save the notes and also the array via NSUserDefaults, so where do I assign the `.hasNote` to the cell?

Comment: That depends on your data model. I was offering an example. You can use indexPath.row to compare to some other index.